# Interview Question

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, analog, inductor, transconductance

This Circuit was given.

[image]

While I possess knowledge of each component within this circuit, including an understanding of feedback and gain margin, as well as familiarity with transconductance amplifiers, my current dilemma revolves around the initial steps of analysis. Initially, I contemplated deriving the transfer function, but I've encountered a roadblock as there is no specified input signal. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in navigating how to commence the analysis process.

Comment: Isn't the input on the pin + of device gm1, as in closed-loop systems? Input = 0 does not change the system.

Comment: `but the problem is no input is given` when analysing the stability the transfer function from "reference" to output should be obtained. Now look at the circuit again and think about where the reference input could be. Plus, think about a transconductance amplifier with "capacitive load".

Comment: As there are obvious ground connections to C1 and Co, perhaps the arrow on V+ of the transconductance amplifier is an input signal, not 0 V. In an interview, that's what I would assume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input signal, say \$V_{in} \$, is the non-inverting input to the transconductance amplifier.

To determine the OLTF, remove the feedback path, giving,

$$\frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)}=\frac{10^{-4}}{10^{-7}s}\times \frac{1}{1+10^{-7}s +10^{-11}s^2}$$

Which simplifies to,

$$\frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)}=\frac{10^{14}}{s(s^2+10^4 s+10^{11})}$$

Hence, the denominator \$s\$ term contributes \$\small-90^o\$ of phase shift.

The 2nd order term is very lightly damped \$\small (\zeta=0.016)\$, so it contributes a further  phase shift of \$\small -90^o\$ (approximately) at the natural frequency, \$\omega _n=\small\sqrt{10^{11}}\: \$ rad/sec.

Therefore, the overall phase shift of \$\small -180^o\$ occurs at or about the natural frequency, \$\omega _n\$.

At \$\omega =\omega_n\$, the loop gain is calculated as, \$\small G=0.1\equiv -20\:dB\$, therefore the Gain Margin is, \$\small GM =20\:dB\$

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking to find the Transfer function but the problem is no input is given.

Inputs are "given", because the two inputs are the inputs of a "substractor".

I have simulated "some" functions to help ...
but it is up to you to find gain & phase margins as usual.

[image]